# not able to scrape data using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I used selenium to scrape data from angel.co but still getting no data from the site

```
from scrapy import Request,Spider

import urllib
from selenium import webdriver

class AngelSpider(Spider):
    name = "angel"
    allowed_domains = ["angel.co"]
    AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED = True
    start_urls = (
        "https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=India",
    )

    def __init__(self):
        self.path ='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver'
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.path)

    def parse(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(50)
        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.more")
            try:
                next.click()
                self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
                divs = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class= 'results']")
                for div in divs:
                    name =divs.find_element_by_css_selector("div.name")
                    print name.text
            except:
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see nothing printed is that you are using the *bare except clause* and basically *silently ignore all the exceptions raised*.

The problem is in the way you find elements on the page, on this line, you are locating a single div element since you are using `find_element_by_xpath()` method:

```
divs = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class= 'results']")
```

`divs` is a *`WebElement` instance now which is not iterable*, iterating over it would fail on the next line:

```
for div in divs:
```

Instead, what you are up to is something like this:

```
results = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".results > div")
for result in results:
    name = result.find_element_by_css_selector(".name")
    print(name.text)
```

Comment: still not able to scrape @alecxe used ` val = response.xpath("//div[@data-_tn = 'companies/results']")
        company_name =val.xpath("//div[@class='name']//text()").extract() ` these two extractor as well these xpaths working fine on chrome but not giving any results on my spider

Comment: Not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. getting no data after scraping and all the xpaths are fine .